# Fastlane with match on Flutter for iOS build

Tags: flutter, fastlane, fastlane-match, fastlane-gym, fastlane-pilot

I'm trying to make fastlane working on Flutter with match for automatic profile signing.
The match profile is working
but when I run the lane deploy I got the following error on the log

Runner.xcodeproj: error: Signing for "Runner" requires a development team. Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

So I'm thing that is something related to the signing while running gym

my fast file

```
default_platform(:ios)

platform :ios do
  desc "Lane deploy"
  lane :deploy do
    match(
          type: 'appstore',
          api_key_path:'/Users/nicolarigoni/Documents/jwt.json',
          app_identifier: 'org.nativescript.intermittentiPlus.IntermittentiEmail',
          git_url:'here the git url for the encrypted certificates'
        )
    gym(
          configuration: "Release",
          workspace: "Runner.xcworkspace",
          scheme: "Runner",
          export_method: "app-store",
          export_options: {
            signingStyle: "manual",
            provisioningProfiles: {
                "org.nativescript.intermittentiPlus.IntermittentiEmail" => 'match AppStore org.nativescript.intermittentiPlus.IntermittentiEmail',
            }
          }
        )
#     pilot(
#           skip_waiting_for_build_processing: true,
#           distribute_external: false,
#           notify_external_testers: false,
#           ipa: "./Runner.ipa"
#         )
  end
end
```

I thing that is something in the provisioning profiles section but I don't know how to write it in the correct way